# Inconsistent accessibility:parameter type is less accessible than a method

Tags: c#

Getting the following error. I'm trying to jump to a new form after clicking a button on first form. I need to pass a list of class objects.

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   is less accessible than method
>   'Preferred_Customer.AddCustomer.AddCustomer(System.Collections.Generic.List)'   C:\Users\Ron\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2013\Projects\Preferred Customer\Preferred
>   Customer\AddCustomer.cs   18  16  Preferred Customer

Here is the code creating the form;

```
private void addCustomerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   AddCustomer myAddCustomer = new AddCustomer(preferredCustomerList);
   myAddCustomer.ShowDialog();
}
```

Here is the code from AddCustomer;

```
namespace Preferred_Customer
{
public partial class AddCustomer : Form
{
    private List<PreferredCustomer> addCustomerList;

    public AddCustomer(List<PreferredCustomer> inPreferredCustomerList)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        addCustomerList = inPreferredCustomerList;

    }
```

Is anyone able to tell what I'm missing?

Comment: Where is the class `PrefferedCustomer` defined? If it's not public, it needs to be.

Comment: Is the class PreferredCustomer private?

Answer (score 2):

Either change the `PrefferedCustomer` from internal to public. (I'm guessing `PrefferedCustomer` is internal unless inside another class declaration)
Or change the `AddCustomer` to `internal` to match the accessibility level

```
 internal partial class AddCustomer : Form
```

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from trying to expose a type in a class at a level more "open" than the one it was declared at. For example:

```
internal interface ISomethingManager {
  // ...
}

public interface IDoSomething {
  public void DoSomething( ISomethingManager manager );
}
```

In this example `ISomethingManager` is internal, but you're exposing it as a method parameter in the public `IDoSomething`. If another assembly wants to call `IDoSomething.DoSomething()`, it would need to know about `ISomethingManager`, which is impossible while it is internal.